# PHP: Is it possible to instantiate objects inside of an array definition?

Tags: php

I would like to define an array that contains newly instantiated objects as values. I tried this:

```
$a = array(
   "foo" => new Foo(),
   "bar" => new Bar(),
)
```

However, this results in a syntax error:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'new' (T_NEW)
```

Is there a way to accomplish this in the array definition itself, or must I instantiate the objects and then add them to the array (not desired)?

Comment: My bet is that your array is a class property, which you try to initialize with this, *right*?

Comment: Your code works for me without any errors. What version ph pfp do you have? Mine: PHP 5.4.28-1

Comment: Yes, @Rizier123, that was my issue, thanks! Code works as expected when called within a method.

Comment: @NathanSmith You're welcome. Seems like you failed a bit with isolating the problem :)

Comment: Not at all. I asked a question and got an answer. Total success. ;)